# MySQL C API mysql_query

Tags: mysql, c, mysql-connector

I have two problems with the MySQL C API. How do I get variable to be added to the table when I do the mysql_query() and how do I get the table show decimals?

Here is my code:

```
void insertDataToTable(MYSQL* con, float temp, int k)
{
    mysql_query(con, "INSERT INTO Weatherstation VALUES(@k,'Temperature:', @temp)");
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: To send variables to the MySQL server, you should [use the prepared statement API](http://lgallardo.com/en/2011/06/23/sentencias-preparadas-de-mysql-en-c-ejemplo-completo/) (sure, you *could* concatenate a string representation of its value into your SQL command—but that gives rise to the possibility of SQL injection, buggy escaping and a needless waste of resources).  It's not clear what you mean by "*get the table show decimals*", please elaborate?

Comment: I send a floating point value to the Weatherstation table like this: mysql_query(con, "INSERT INTO Weatherstation VALUES(1, 'Temperature:', 124.3)"); But when I logged into the database and checked that value from the table it showed just 124 without the decimal part.

Comment: What is the [data type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/data-types.html) of the relevant column?

Comment: Oh yes of course, there is the problem! I have specified it as an integer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
void insertDataToTable(MYSQL* con, float temp, int k)
{
    char query[255] ;

    sprintf( query, "INSERT INTO Weatherstation VALUES(%ld,'Temperature:', %d)", temp, k );
    mysql_query(con, query );


}
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not support host variables that well, the previous answer shows the correct approach in building the query into a string and then using mysql_query(someconnection, string).

What is absolutely shocking is that this is not documented as much as it should be. When I had to learn this I had 30 years of DB2 and C, and I had to get this from GitHub after 2 hours of fruitless searching for "MySQL Host Variables".

You should also be aware of mysql_real_query if your query is not a conventional string and contains embedded nulls, it is passed the length of the string, but can also move a strlen() call off the server.